# "go list" command prints hint I dont understand

Tags: go

When running the following command:

```
go list -m -u all
```

a message is printed stating:

```
go: updates to go.sum needed, disabled by -mod=readonly
```

I am not sure how to interpret this message. I have checked the `go list` command and it does not have any `mod` flags. Can anyone offer suggestions on how to handle or understand this message? Thank you.

Comment: This message suggests that updates are required to the go.sum file to ensure that the Go modules are up-to-date, but the go command has been run with the -mod=readonly flag which prevents any updates to the module dependencies. To fix this, you need to run the go command without the -mod=readonly flag, so that the required updates can be made to the go.sum file.

You can simply run the go command again without the -mod=readonly flag to make the required updates to the go.sum file. For example:
`go get -u all`

Comment: Unfortunately, the `go get -u all` command prints nothing and changes nothing about the output of the list command.

Also tried to remove the go.sum file and regenerate with `go mod tidy`, but still prints this message abour readonly

Comment: What version of Go are you running? `-mod=readonly` has [been the default](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-updates) since Go 1.16 (the fact its the default does make the error messages a bit confusing!). Does `go list` output anything else? You could try adding `-mod=mod` (but  this should not generally be needed). If you are able to share a minimal example that would be helpful (but I understand this may be difficult to create!).

Comment: Using go version 1.20.5

After digging further I found that in my case, the package

`github.com/labstack/echo/v4`

caused the problem. If I create a brand new project, as soon as the `echo` package is used, the `go list -m -u all` stops working.

So in my case the problem is identified - thank you for the hints!

Now since I'm quite new to go the thing left for me would be to know why this very module causes the issue or where to look for potential cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is a regression introduced in a previous patch release (Go1.20.5 and Go1.19.10). See this bug report: [cmd/go: go list fails with submodules which have test-only dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/60667).

The issue has already been fixed on the tip, and will be backported to Go1.20 (milestone Go1.20.6) and Go1.19 (milestone Go1.19.11).